# Add drop shadow to slide out navigation

Tags: android

I have implemented slide out navigation using [this](https://github.com/gitgrimbo/android-sliding-menu-demo). [image: current implementation]

The content should drop shadow near menu list's right edge; like [image: expected result]

I'm trying to add shadow by adding a view to content left edge, but it wont show up.

Any clue on how to do this will be appreciated.

Comment: This question has lost it's importance now. I was trying to do it when Facebook was the only app that used this kind of navigation. There were no libraries to make the same UI. There were few concepts and half baked code. Just about 8-9 months later libraries started popping up with all kind of customization and then answer also started coming. I'm not sure if I could have accepted one of the answers, not even sure now. These are too specific to some library or approach and still on closer to the concept I was trying.

Answer (score 11):

Guys I know I am late to the party but i had a hard time finding an answer to this issue that was satisfactory to me so i just wanted to share my solution to this. Fist, create a drawable navbar_shadow.xml and put it with the rest of your drawables. All it is, is a rectangle with a transparent gradient.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#111"
        android:endColor="#00000000">
    </gradient>
    <size
        android:height="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:width="5dp">
    </size>
</shape>
```

Then, wherever you are instantiating your drawer, use your DrawerLayout variable to attach it to your drawer.

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.navbar_shadow, Gravity.LEFT);
```

Bam. No need to draw line by line or include any extra resources. You can use your own startColor to match your drawer color, but endColor should remain #00000000 as it is a transparent black.

Comment: Perfect! And by changing the `startColor`, `endColor` also works for right slide menu.

Comment: nice solution but unfortunately I seem to have a space between the shadow and the drawer when fully opened

Comment: Make sure the darker end of the drawable gradient is positioned toward your drawer side- this given solution was made for a lift side drawer. IF you are working with a right drawer, you might need to reverese stard/end colors.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is quite old but I had trouble finding a solution so I thought it might help somebody if I posted mine here.

I wanted to add a fade to black on the right had side of this simple ListView.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/sideMenuList"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Created a PNG file with a gradient [using GIMP](http://blog.bottomlessinc.com/2008/06/opaque-to-transparent-gradient-on-layers-in-gimp/). Add it to /res/drawable. Mine was named fade_from_right.png

Surrounded the ListView with a RelativeLayout. Give the RelativeLayout the background color you want your ListView to have.

Add another View to the right of your ListView. Set the new views background to be your 'fade_from_right.png'

Thats it.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:background="@color/solarized_base02">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/sideMenuList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <View
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/sideMenuList"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/fade_from_right"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is really old indeed. @brett did the above solution worked for you. I now use https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Comment: I looked at using SlidingMenu but, being new to android I want to keep things as simple as possible so I'm instead using the very simple https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/AndroidSideMenu. That being said, my solution is not specific to AndroidSideMenu, so can be used to apply a shadow to any sort of view.

Answer (score 0):

what is the need to add another  view with the listview, it will not be perfect i think.. You may try like this right?

```
sm = getSlidingMenu();
sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadowbar);
```

since we may set some behindView width and offset. this option will give a good look i think.

Comment: Thanks @Tamilselvan, but this was posted before the era of jfeinstein's SlidingMenu (at least before I discovered).